# Find out if there are CRLF (i.e. \r\n) committed in the Git and which commits introduce them

Tags: git, line-endings, core.autocrlf

Sometimes I find out that there are CRLF line-endings committed in Git history. The project has many teammembers, so I'd like to find which commits have been adding CRLF, so I can contact the authors (I assume they didn't select the "checkout Windows-style, commit Linux style" option in the Git install wizard for Windows).

[image]

Comment: Use `.gitattributes` then no team member has to manually configure autocrlf.

Answer (score 2):

Disable AutoCrLf (`git config --global core.autocrlf false`), clone the repository and search for CrLf (e.g., using [GrepWin](https://sourceforge.net/projects/grepwin/), search for `\r\n`). Then blame the files you found and contact the team members.

PS: Use [`.gitattributes`](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitattributes) then no team member has to manually configure autocrlf (e.g., set `* text=auto` or `*.cpp text eol=lf`).

PSS: Converting all files in the working tree can be done by `git rm --cached *` followed by a `git reset --hard HEAD`.

Comment: Great solution! Do you think there is a way to also find CRLF that were committed at some point but later a team member with different CRLF settings re-committed them properly? I'm asking because I'd like to catch commits at any point, not just those that reach to the current HEAD. I'm hoping to find a flag for `git log -p` but so far, I've come up with nothing.